# Adding extra information

Tags: punctuation

The bourgeois in Germany, like Saxony Frederick, initially had quarrels with church.

My question:
"Like Saxony Frederick" is extra information in the sentence, I always thought you could put commas around the extra Info and it would work. Like ,Extra info, is this correct or should use parentheses or some other method.

Comment: The punctuation is fine. But who is *Saxony Frederick*?

Comment: Saxony Frederick was Luther's main supporter during the protestant revolution

Comment: Ah, you mean *Frederick of Saxony* - that is the proper style for a territorial prince. And he was hardly a bourgeois, but one of the most prominent aristocrats in the Empire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parentheses vs. double commas vs. dashes to provide additional detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/parentheses-vs-double-commas-vs-dashes-to-provide-additional-detail)

Comment: Re your use of *bourgeois*: you have, first of all, used the adjective as though it were the noun, which is *bourgeoisie*. At its most literal *bourgeoisie* is the French for 'town-dwellers'. But modern usage derives from Marx's nomenclature for the class of people who uphold capitalism in industrial society. There is a  record of the former use in English, per the OED, in 1593, but nothing further till 1683. I am wondering about the relevance of such a French word in the Holy Roman Empire (Germany) during the life of Luther (1483-1546). I sense the word you meant was *aristocracy*.

Comment: @WS2 English frequently allows adjectives to be used as nouns, to refer to the people or objects described by the adjective. E.g. _the poor_.

Comment: @StoneyB The sentence isn't saying Frederick is bourgeois. It's saying "Like Frederick of Saxony, the bourgeoisie in Germany initially had quarrels with the church."

Comment: @Mynamite That's a reading I hadn't thought of; but if that's what was meant the author should have flipped the *like* phrase to the front to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about putting commas around extraneous information in your sentence. This is called an **appositive.** The best guideline I can give you for writing appositive clauses is that they can be removed from the sentence completely, and the sentence will still make perfect sense (sort of like prepositional phrases).

> The bourgeois in Germany initially had quarrels with [the] church.

Parenthesis are a stylistic choice. I would advise against using them if you're trying to write a formal piece, although academic papers will likely require that you include parenthetical citations. I tend to use them frequently, usually one or two times a post. The advantage of using parenthesis is that you don't have to change the structure of your sentence in order to add extra information. I've also seen dashes used to substitute for commas in an appositive clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any hard and fast rules about parentheses.

But, AFAICT phrases in parentheses are not supposed to substantially modify the core meaning of the sentences outside of the parentheses - meaning if you remove the parenthetical phrase, the whole paragraph may be less interesting, but not really change in meaning.

So it depends how critical "like Saxony Frederick" is to the entire sentence.  If this is just interesting information you are bringing up to enhance the paragraph, but not change its core meaning, parentheses are OK.  If the words are crucial to the thread of the paragraph, don't use them.

> I took this bike, with a flat tire, to the park.  While riding it, I hit a bump, fell, and scratched my knee.

OK.

> I took this bike (with a flat tire) to the park.  While riding it, I hit a bump, fell, and scratched my knee.

Less than OK, because without the phrase "with a flat tire", the meaning changes (we no longer can know the cause of your falling if you leave that phrase out).

> I took this bike, painted a beautiful red, to the park.

OK.

> I took this bike (painted a beautiful red) to the park.

Also OK, but not as interesting.